# Local folder upload through SSH

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, plesk

I am quite new to using SSH. I want to upload an entire local folder from my mac to my server.

Through the Mac Terminal, I am connected with my server. 
With SSH I am already inside the path where the folder should be placed.

I need to use the command su- to get root access, so that I am allowed to upload files into this filder.

So I can not connect through the server with an SSH command with the account details inside it.

So `scp -r /home/user/Desktop/ user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo` will not work because I cannot get directly root access.

I need to upload it into this folder on my server /usr/share/psa-roundcube/skins/

How can I upload the folder through SSH?

Comment: It is not clear whether you have *root* access on this server or not: do you know the password? Can't you temporarily change the owner of `foo` using `chown` ?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Sorry, I currently do have root acces. But I can not get root access directly, I first need to run the command "su-" to get root access.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo and http://askubuntu.com/questions/208378/how-do-i-copy-files-that-need-root-access-with-scp

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy files to `/tmp/`
2. `ssh` into remote server and become root
3. `mv` files from `/tmp/` to `/path/to/foo/`
4. `cd` into `/path/to/foo/`
5. `ls -l` to check permissions, fix with `chmod`/`chown` if anything's wrong